# Android studio - problems opening file with openFileInput

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using this method:

```
public String retrieve(){

    String fileName = "lifeClockSavedData";
    String message ="";


    try {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("lifeClockSavedData");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null);{stringBuffer.append(message + "\n");}



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return message;
}
```

to retrieve a String from a file: lifeClockSavedData.It works fine when called from within its own class (MainActivity). When I try to call it from another class using:

```
    MainActivity dataLoad = new MainActivity();

    String texty = dataLoad.retrieve();
```

The app crashes out with a NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

Hand-holding would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to this and not all that clever.

Comment: **Never** create a component instance yourself via the constructor. Also, do not do I/O, such as reading data from disk, on the main application thread. You are freezing the UI while this work is being done. As part of migrating this work into a background thread, your `retrieve()` code will need a `Context`, on which it can call `openFileInput()`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. That's stopped it crashing out.